# How is Java Optional different from traditional handling of missing value? Or how to use Java Optional correctly

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

It seems to me Optional adds little to code flow control and missing values handling. If a value behind an optional is not found, one still have to deal with absence of the value - then what's the point?

Compare:

```
Optional someMissingVal = codeThatReturnsOptional.getOptionalValue().orElse(null);
if( someMissingVal == null){
    throw(new NullPointerException());
} 
else return someMissingVal.get();
```

vs

```
Type someMissingVal = codeThatReturnsType.getTypeValue();
    if( someMissingVal == null){
        throw(new NullPointerException());
    } 
    else return someMissingVal;
```

So what's the big deal and how do I use Optional to harness its full power in the scenario above - as opposed to the "old style" missing value handling?

Comment: Good question. I'm not java-8-super-hacker, but seems some examples in net are wrong (in "old" style), especially when calling stack is deep

Comment: In your first example, `someMissingVal` is not of type `Optional`. Besides that, both examples are flawed. When you invoke a method that is documented to potentially return `null` (or an empty optional), there is no point in throwing a `NullPointerException` if it does. You are expected to *handle* the scenario. Besides that, enforcing a non-`null` value can be done much simpler: `return Objects.requireNonNull( codeThatReturnsType.getTypeValue());`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `null` checks on the fly like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = null;
    String newS = Optional.ofNullable(s).orElse("default");
}
```

As well as throw exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = null;
    String newS = Optional.ofNullable(s).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

Use some conditional statements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "test";
    Optional.ofNullable(s).ifPresent(System.out::print);
}
```

Use it with `Streams` in more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your first snippet as following

```
return codeThatReturnsOptional.getOptionalValue()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException());
```

Does it simplify your code now? And it makes it readable too.

You can do a lot with Optional. This [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) from Oracle explains it.